# Cannot resolve the name 'common:DateRange' to a(n) 'type definition' component

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, schema

I have two xml schema files schema1.xsd schema2.xsd.
schema2.xsd is imported inside schema1.xsd
Whan i try to parse schema1.xsd in JAXB as the following:

```
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(schemaString));
```

I got the following exception:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 62; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'common:DateRange' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
```

**Schema1.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com" xmlns="http://www.example.com"
    xmlns:common="http://www.example.com/common">

<xs:import namespace="http://www.example.com/common" schemaLocation="schema2.xsd" />

    <xs:element name="exType" type="ExampleType" />
    <xs:complexType name="ExampleType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
                <xs:element name="activeDates" type="common:DateRange" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Schema2.xsd:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://www.example.com/common" 
targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/common">

    <xs:complexType name="DateRange">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="startDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
            <xs:element name="endDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved when i defined the full path of the schema2.xsd path

Comment: did you specify relative path under schemaLocation of calling xsd?